# How To Handle Files Opened Via An Erlang gen_server?

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I've created a module which transparently handles certain files in completely different ways, acting as a replacement for Erlang's `file:open/2` and the IoDevice/file descriptor it returns. In many cases it's simply returning the result of Erlang's `file:open/2`, and in other cases it's returning a custom IoDevice which reads and writes via a HTTP API (CloudFiles or AWS S3).

Recently this was a plain module, but I've been attempting to convert it to a `gen_server` to better handle asynchronous HTTP calls (among other reasons). These custom bits are functioning fine, but I'm having trouble simply calling `file:open/2` from a `gen_server:handle_call/3` and returning the resulting IoDevice. The issue is after my `gen_server` opens a file in order to reply with an IoDevice, there is an immediate, unexpected call to `gen_server:handle_info/2` and an eventual timeout on my `gen_server`.

```
...
handle_call({open, Path, Flags}, _From, State) ->
    Reply = case handle_external_file(Path) of
                false -> file:open(Path, Flags);
                true -> external_file:open(Path)
            end,
    %%
    %% Reply is {ok,{file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1896>,14}}}
    %%
    {reply, Reply, State};
...
handle_info(Message, State) ->
    %%
    %% Message is {#Port<0.1896>,{data,[3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}}
    %%
    io:format("UNEXPECTED MESSAGE: ~p~n", [Message]),
    {noreply, State}
...
```

I assume this is related to the following from the docs:

> IoDevice is really the pid of the process which handles the file. This process is linked to the process which originally opened the file. If any process to which the IoDevice is linked terminates, the file will be closed and the process itself will be terminated. An IoDevice returned from this call can be used as an argument to the IO functions (see io(3)).

Is there a way to open a file from a `gen_server`, handing its IoDevice over to another process?

Comment: i think you should let the `gen_server` spawn the process which will use the file. and then let that process open the file, and use it. It is not possible to use the gen_server to open the file, and yet expect a different process to use the returned `file descriptor`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the file:open the issue is with the port driver opened in external_file:open(Path). The IoDevice can be used by any process but it will be available only till the creating process exists. Whereas the process which creates the port driver becomes the owner of the port driver and only that process can communicate with the port driver. If the Port ref is returned and any other process accesses it, the program can crash.

The better approach would be that you do not return the Port. Instead get the data as message and use the same gen_server to read/write to the port.